# How to transform a noncommutative product to a different expression?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have a (long) sum of the following ** (noncommutative) products:

```
gg**qs**rh
```

(each variable always consists of two letters like in the artificial example above and the 'length' of the product varies) and I would like to tranform it into the following ordinary multiplication:

```
ipgq ipsr ipgh
```

where ipxy is a variable created by merging 'ip' with the symbols surrounding each ** (in this case gq and sr) and the last one created from the outermost two symbols (gh). The order of xy's matters but the product order of ipxy's does not since it is the usual multiplication.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: It would be useful to have a specific example, in Mathematica form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
pro2Sum[pro_] := Module[{str, part, f},
str = Table[
DeleteCases[DeleteCases[Characters[ToString[pro[[i]]]], " "], 
 "*"], {i, 1, Length[pro]}];
 part = Table[
Partition[
 Join[Drop[Drop[str[[i]], -1], 1], Take[str[[i]], 1], 
  Take[str[[i]], -1]], 2], {i, 1, Length[str]}];
f[a_, b_] := "ip" <> ToString[a] <> ToString[b];
Total[Times @@@ Table[f @@@ part[[i]], {i, 1, Length[part]}]]
 ]

npr = gg ** qs ** rh + ab ** cd ** ef;
pro2Sum[npr]
(*"ipaf" "ipbc" "ipde" + "ipgh" "ipgq" "ipsr"*)
```

---

Define your product

```
npr = gg ** qs ** rh
```

Convert to string and remove blank space and the asterisks

```
str = DeleteCases[DeleteCases[Characters[ToString[npr]]," "], "*"]

(*{"g", "g", "q", "s", "r", "h"}*)
```

Partition the list

```
 part = Partition[
 Join[Drop[Drop[str, -1], 1], Take[str, 1], Take[str, -1]], 2]

 (*{{"g", "q"}, {"s", "r"}, {"g", "h"}}*)
```

Make a formatting function

```
  f[a_, b_] := "ip" <> ToString[a] <> ToString[b]
```

Use it to format the partitioned list

```
  f @@@ part

  (*{"ipgq", "ipsr", "ipgh"}*)
```

Comment: This is very cool but how do I apply it 'linearly' ? As I wrote, I have a long sum of these products and I want to end up with a sum of 'ip' products. I cannot take summands one by one, apply your map and assemble it back.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I may be expressing myself in a lousy way but the output of pro2Sum[npr] should be  ipgq ipsr ipgh+ipaf ipbc ipde. Or just {"ipgq", "ipsr", "ipgh"} and {"ipaf ", "ipbc ", "ipde"} so that I know from what summand the new ip expressions come from.

Comment: check update. Just remove the `Total` and `Times` to get in the list format.

Answer (score 1):

```
pro = ab ** cd;

cha = Characters @ StringReplace[ToString @ pro, "*" | " " -> ""];

par = Partition[cha[[2 ;; -2]]~Join~cha[[{1, -1}]], 2]
```

> {{"b", "c"}, {"a", "d"}}

```
Times @@ ToExpression[StringJoin /@ Prepend["ip"] /@ par]
```

> ipad ipbc

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to avoid naming variables in this way when individual characters of the name are going to be operated and instead name them in such a way that those elements can be accessed easily without string conversion (say using something like `Subscript[a,2]` instead of `a2` or the like).

In your case, if changing your convention isn't difficult to your remaining code, I'd recommend something like

```
a**g.q**s.r**h
```

This way, you have two distinct forms of noncommutative multiplication. I swapped the `NonCommutativeMultiplication` with `Dot` from what you were using rather than simply adding `Dot` between the letters because doing that was structurally different from your desired representation due to the operator precedence relationship between `NonCommutativeMultiply` and `Dot`.

Then, we can use functions that access elements of your variables easily and define

```
Clear[f]
f[a_Plus] := Map[f, a]
f[a_Dot] := 
 Dot @@ Map[i**p**# &]@
   MapAt[Reverse, 
    ListConvolve[{1, 2}, List @@ a, {-1, -1}, a[[1]], #2[[#1]] &, 
     NonCommutativeMultiply], -1]
f[a**g.q**s.r**h + g**g.q**s.r**h]
```

> ```
> i**p**g**q.i**p**s**r.i**p**a**h + i**p**g**q.i**p**s**r.i**p**g**h
> ```

Comment: This is nice but @Hubble07's answer is more suitable for my purposes. In reality, the two-letter expressions are rank-one operators (like |ket><bra| in QM), ** is non-com multiplication and what I need to find is simply the trace of a long sum of these products. I rephrased it as a symbolic sequence manipulation task since none of the QM extensions of Mathematica I found suits my purposes.

Comment: Sparse matrices would be much more suitable to that purpose.